Eigenvalue under Lorentz metric

I'm currently reading Hawking and Ellis and came across a statement regarding eigenvalues of a matrix under the Lorentz metric, represented by $diag\{1,1,1,-1\}$. A matrix $T$ is defined as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & p_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \nu-k & \nu \\
0 & 0 & \nu & \nu+k
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
The text claims that ((0,0,1,1)^T) is a double null eigenvector. I'm confused about this claim. Could there be an error in my understanding, or are eigenvalues for the Lorentz metric defined differently?
Thank you for your assistance.

Note that $T^{a}{}{b}k^b=\lambda k^{a}$ implies $T^{ab}k_b=\lambda g^{ab}k{b}$, which can be written as $(T^{ab}-\lambda g^{ab})k_b=0^a$.
So, use $0=\det(T^{ab}-\lambda g^{ab})$.

Thanks. I thought it was still $(T-\lambda I)\vec{v}=0$
